# How to get word processor like column-orientated "text"-flow via HTML+CSS?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-multicolumn-layout

To find a meaningful title was difficult for me.

I try to force my HTML document to have same text flow behavior like typical word processors have.

Please take a look at the following container flow:

```
   1   2   3
|-------------|
| ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ |
| ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ |
| ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ |
| ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ |
| ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ |
| ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ |
| ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ |
| ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ |
|-------------|
   4   5  (6)
|-------------|
| ~~~ ~~~     |
| ~~~ ~~~     |
| ~~~ ~~~     |
| ~~~ ~~~     |
| ~~~         |
| ~~~         |
| ~~~         |
| ~~~         |
|-------------|
```

The three tildes mean a rendered container element and the numbers show the order of content-flow.

The following HTML/CSS code was a first try with a very unsatisfying result.

```css
html { 
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: coral;
}
p {
  width: 33%;
}
.din-a7 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 74mm;
  height: 105mm;
}
.print-margin-10mm {
  padding: 10mm;
}
```

```html
<div class="din-a7 print-margin-10mm two-column-text-flow">
  <p>01 content</p>
  <p>02 content</p>
  <p>03 content</p>
  <p>04 content</p>
  <p>05 content</p>
  <p>06 content</p>
  <p>07 content</p>
  <p>08 content</p>
  <p>09 content</p>
  <p>10 content</p>
  <p>11 content</p>
  <p>12 content</p>
  <p>13 content</p>
  <p>14 content</p>
  <p>15 content</p>
  <p>16 content</p>
  <p>17 content</p>
  <p>18 content</p>
  <p>19 content</p>
  <p>20 content</p>
  <p>21 content</p>
  <p>22 content</p>
  <p>23 content</p>
  <p>24 content</p>
  <p>25 content</p>
  <p>26 content</p>
  <p>27 content</p>
  <p>28 content</p>
  <p>29 content</p>
  <p>30 content</p>
  <p>31 content</p>
  <p>32 content</p>
  <p>33 content</p>
  <p>34 content</p>
  <p>35 content</p>
  <p>36 content</p>
  <p>37 content</p>
</div>
```

I have tried to use `column-count` but it works only with simple text instead of containers and also the wrap to the next "page" doesn't work.

Is this possible with simple HTML/CSS anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a container having `column-count: 3` to create three columns with continuous, automatic text flow.

But since there are no pages in HTML, there is no second page to continue.

And it's *not* possible to have text content flow dynamically from one container (div, span, p, whatever) into another one (i.e. the way text flows from page 1 to page 2 in a Word document or similar).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Bootstrap´s grid like this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">




  <title></title>

</head>

<body>


  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
      <p>01 content</p>
      <p>02 content</p>
      <p>03 content</p>
      <p>04 content</p>
      <p>05 content</p>
      <p>06 content</p>
      <p>07 content</p>
      <p>08 content</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-4">
      <p>09 content</p>
      <p>10 content</p>
      <p>11 content</p>
      <p>12 content</p>
      <p>13 content</p>
      <p>14 content</p>
      <p>15 content</p>
      <p>16 content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    <p>17 content</p>
    <p>18 content</p>
    <p>19 content</p>
    <p>20 content</p>
    <p>21 content</p>
    <p>22 content</p>
    <p>23 content</p>
    <p>24 content</p>
    </div>

    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
      <p>25 content</p>
      <p>26 content</p>
      <p>27 content</p>
      <p>28 content</p>
      <p>29 content</p>
      <p>30 content</p>
      <p>31 content</p>
      <p>32 content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p>33 content</p>
      <p>34 content</p>
      <p>35 content</p>
      <p>36 content</p>
      <p>37 content</p>
      </div>
    </div> 
  


  <!-- axios -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Answer boiler.js"></script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```